# DCOM configuration for Win 10

Tags: windows-10, dcom

Where can I find up-to-date information on configuring remote DCOM access on a modern Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise system? The last time I did this was for Windows 7 and I dare say that a lot has changed. Searching online for information turns up a great many obsolete articles and books.

Under Windows 7 I had managed to do it for a Linux Java program using the old j-interop library, supplying the account name, password and Class ID. Since it *is* so old, j-interop uses only the NTLMv1 and v2 protocols. I'd like to make this combination work again for Windows 10. In a general way I recall that you have to make firewall rules exposing a port-mapper port and the ports it may open. Then you have use DCOM configuration to allow your account access to the particular server. But I don't know how to do those things now and don't know what else may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end the answer turned out to be "Don't do it that way!". I ended up writing a web server to read the data using local OPC DA and then export it via HTTP. Basically Python Bottle + OpenOPC. A commercial OPC UA gateway with local OPC DA capablility would also have worked.